# Is my .HTACCESS file setup right or is it me?

Tags: php, .htaccess

so I'm currently hosting my server locally on my machine for testing on a virtualbox using Oracle. The system I'm using is Ubuntu. I have everything installed, but when I load index.php, it's suppose to redirect to main.tpl (A Template File).

Here is my .HTaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(\w+)$ index.php?page=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(\w+)+\/$ index.php?page=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http%1://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

order allow,deny
deny from 46.101.200.204
allow from all
```

This sets the location when index.php is loaded. It sets main.tpl:

```
if (!isset($_GET['page'])) {
    header('Location: /main');
    exit();
}
```

The error code when I load the page:

```
The requested URL /main was not found on this server.
```

It's suppose to open main.tpl (Template)

If you need any more information provided please tell me and I'll do so, if you have a solution or some steps that'll be great! Thanks!

~mrgreen33gamer | Joshy

Comment: nothing in the code redirects to `main.tpl` or anything like that

Comment: I updated it. But "header('Location: /main');" is loaded when index.php is loaded. The page is directed to main.tpl. Which is main.